# Como incluir novo icone a direita em uma activity Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

É possível incluir um novo icone em uma `activity` porém a direita, sem alterar o já existente ?

Preciso incluir a foto do usuário a direita.

(Local vermelho na imagem)

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível sim, para fazer isso você precisa adicionar um novo "ToolbarItem" a sua barra de tarefas. 
Caso você esteja desenvolvendo a página diretamente em C# você pode fazer da seguinte maneira

```
this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("nome", "icone", () => 
        {
            // ação ao clicar no icone
        }, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
```

Onde:

- O "nome" seria o nome a aparecer quando o usuário apertasse e segurasse o ícone, ou se não houver uma imagem de ícone, nesse caso o texto fica por extenso.
- O "icone" seria o ícone que você irá usar para a opção, nesse caso a imagem do usuário
- A expressão lambida "() => { //código aqui }" serviria para executar alguma ação ao clicar no ícone (aka. Foto do usuário =P )
- E o "ToolbarItemOrder.Primary" serve para indicar a posição que o item ficará no menu, se você colocar "ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary" o item ficará em um menu de opções (O mesmo lugar que você costuma encontrar as "Configurações" de um app, aquele menu com três pontinhos "..."), já se você colocar "ToolbarItemOrder.Primary" ele se mostrará como um item no menu, mostrando o ícone que você definiu a ele ou a foto do usuário no seu caso =)

Espero ter ajudado =)

Comment: onde que adiciono essa nova ToolbarItem ? Na Activity ?

Comment: Exato, no exemplo, eu estou criando a minha tela diretamente pelo código, ou seja, não possuo o layout _XAML_, então eu o adiciono no construtor da classe, a que herda de **ContentPage**

Comment: consegui, só não sei agora como faço pra exibir a imagem lá sem o component Image. manja ?

Comment: A imagem do usuário ficará guardada no Dispositivo ou ela será baixada da internet?

Comment: Estou retornando ela do BD pra uma propriedade. Não posso usar essa propriedade pra exibir a foto ?

Comment: huuum, você retorna a imagem inteira do BD ou o Caminho para ela no dispositivo?

Comment: talvez se você alterar a propriedade de imagem do objeto "ToolbarItem" e indicar o arquivo que você esteja querendo mostrar pode ser possível, mas não posso te dizer com certeza, pois nunca fiz desta forma =\

Comment: eu tentei fazer isso mas não funcionou. hehe. tranquilo. valeu

Comment: Nada, caso chegue a uma solução poste a resposta aqui, será legal saber como chegou nela =D

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira seria assim:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Usuario" Order="Primary" Priority="0">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
                    WinPhone="Toolkit.Content/imagem.png"
                    Android="imagem.png"
                    iOS="imagem.png"
                    />
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```